# Import Figure to Latex in Scientific Workplace vs Miktex

Tags: floats

I use Miktex and have the following code to transfer a .png image to a pdfLatex document:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure1.png} }
\caption{text}
\label{figure1}
\end{figure}
```

My colleague uses Latex in Scientific Workplace and he tells me that this code of mine does not work for him, he simply gets the path of the figures written on the figures. Could anybody help us fix this code? How should we change the above code so that it is workable on the Scientific Workplace too? We will greatly appreciate some guidance... Thanks so much for your patience!

Comment: Does your collegue use the draft option?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you should fix the example `\centering` does not take an argument so

```
\centering{...}
```

should be

```
\centering
```

delete the spurious braces.

Also `[h]` almost always generates a warning that it is being changed to `[ht]` so it is better to use an option that gives latex a chance to position the figure.

Then finally to address the main issue, do not use the extension then the latex (or pdflatex) implementation will input the image format that it can handle

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure1}
\caption{text}
\label{figure1}
\end{figure}
```

Then your colleague needs to save `figure1.png` in a format the scientific workplace can handle (you will need to check the SW documentation) probably `figure1.eps` will work.